# Batch renaming documents in VBA by first line, how to skip non-text?

Tags: vba, ms-word, batch-rename

I have a folder full of Word Documents which has recently been "undeleted", while the contents of these files are viewable all metadata has been lost (Most importantly, original file names). I have found a VBA script that will run through a folder and rename any .doc files with the first line of its content.

The scripts works just as expected with documents that contain only text, although many of the files I need renamed are headed with an image. When the script gets to these files it ends and only the files up to that point are renamed.

I have very limited programming knownledge and know next to nothing about VBA but I imagine that I could skip the image with an if|else type statement and use the next line of text as the file name. My problem is I have no idea on how to accomplish this. Also, a method of removing any spaces which appear before the first line of text would be very helpful but is much less important.

The script I am currently working with is as follows:

```
Public Sub BatchReNameFiles()

Dim myFile As String
Dim PathToUse As String
Dim myDoc As Document
Dim NewName As String
Dim OldName As String
Dim oRng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

'Specify folder where files are located
PathToUse = "C:\Test\"
'Count files in folder
OldName = Dir$(PathToUse & "*.doc")
While OldName <> ""
i = i + 1
OldName = Dir$()
Wend
'Rename files
j = 0
myFile = Dir$(PathToUse & "*.doc")
Do While myFile <> "" And j < i
j = j + 1
Set myDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=PathToUse & myFile, Visible:=False)
With myDoc
OldName = .FullName
Set oRng = .Words(1)
oRng.End = .Words(min(9, .Words.Count - 1)).End
NewName = Trim(oRng.Text) & ".doc"
NewName = Replace(NewName, "\", "")
NewName = Replace(NewName, ":", "")
NewName = Replace(NewName, """", "")
NewName = Replace(NewName, vbCr, "")
NewName = Replace(NewName, vbTab, "")
.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
End With
Name OldName As PathToUse & NewName
myFile = Dir$()
Loop

End Sub
Private Function min(a As Long, b As Long)
min = -((a < b) * a + (a >= b) * b)
End Function
```

I take no credit for this script, I found it as is while browsing the web looking for a solution. If anyone has any insight into this problem I would greatly appreciate a response.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 x64 Word 2003. This is crazy. Try a minimum like I am posting in an EDIT of my answer. Then add/uncomment more statements. I can't think any re-install would make a difference, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"My problem is I have no idea on how to accomplish this." I don't think this is how SO was designed to operate, but I think I can use this routine also. So here's my version, which I think is better. The 'net is short on VBA tutorials, but this looks good: http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/VBABasicsIn15Mins.htm.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub BatchReNameFiles()
  Const sPath = "c:\test\" ' could do FileDialog
  Dim OldName$, NewName$, openDoc As Document
  ThisDocument.Content.Delete
  OldName = Dir$(sPath & "*.doc", vbNormal)
  Do While OldName <> ""
    ThisDocument.Activate
    Selection.TypeText OldName & " -> "
    Set openDoc = Documents.Open(sPath & OldName)
    openDoc.Activate
    NewName = getChars(20) & ".doc"
    openDoc.Close
    ThisDocument.Activate
    If NewName <> ".doc" Then
      Selection.TypeText NewName
      On Error GoTo zError
      Name sPath & OldName As NewName
      On Error GoTo 0 ' reset
    End If
    Selection.TypeText vbCrLf
    DoEvents
    OldName = Dir$()
  Loop
Exit Sub
zError:
  Selection.TypeText "Error: " & Err.Description
  Resume Next
End Sub

Function getChars$(nChars&) ' get good characters
  Dim s1$, sChar$
  Selection.HomeKey wdStory
  Do
    sChar = Chr$(Asc(Selection.Text)) ' one character
    If "0" <= sChar And sChar <= "9" Or _
       "A" <= sChar And sChar <= "Z" Or _
       "a" <= sChar And sChar <= "z" Then
      s1 = s1 & sChar
      If Len(s1) = nChars Then Exit Do
    End If
  Loop While Selection.MoveRight(1, wdCharacter) <> 0
  getChars = s1
End Function
```

EDIT: Try this minimum and add/uncomment statements to it. I'm baffled.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub BatchReNameFiles()
'  Const sPath = "c:\test\" ' could do FileDialog
'  Dim OldName$, NewName$, openDoc As Document
'  ThisDocument.Content.Delete
'  OldName = Dir$(sPath & "*.doc", vbNormal)
'  ThisDocument.Activate
  Selection.TypeText "This is data"
'  Selection.TypeText OldName & " -> "
End Sub
```

Comment: I appricate your response, this is my first time using StackOverflow so I apologize if I did not follow proper etiquette with my question (I am a computer technician and have a limited familiarization with programming in general).

Comment: Anyway, I have ran your script and I received a Run-Time error '91' upon reaching line 10. It states a varible has not been set, I assume this is because the object Oldname has not been set. Although it appears that you have set that  in line 5 with 'Dim OldName$'. I don't expect a response but I would greatly appreciate any further assitance.In the meantime I will be working through the tuturial you suggested to better fimilarize myself with VBA in general, thank you again.

Comment: @Cody Istre - Yes, `Dim OldName$` declares the variable and `OldName = Dir$(sPath & "*.doc", vbNormal)` gives it a value. You can single-step using F8. You can view a variable by hovering over it (dang, there's a word for that). A better link is http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/index.htm

Comment: Thanks, I have been working through the debugger line-by-line and it seems to error every time it reaches "Selection.TypeText". For testing I removed every line containing it so I could run through the rest of the script (No other errors where received). When hovering over 'NewName' the variable displays perfectly (First line of text with no spaces) and it moves through each file in the directory as expected. Although, since removing those lines it does not actually make changes to the files, which I expected.

Comment: From what I gather 'Selection.TypeText' is the command that actually writes the data from the NewName variable to the file. So if I understand correctly (although I feel like I'm way off), 'Selection' should refer to the data in the NewName variable and 'TypeText' will then write that information to the file.

Comment: @Cody Istre - (I don't get the Run-Time error) The `Selection.TypeText ..` statements are preceded by `ThisDocument.Activate` statements, so the `OldName & " -> "` etc. gets written to ThisDocument as a log of what is being renamed. We will soon be asked to carry this thread to a Chat -- that will be no problem.

Comment: Ok, I've been trying to work through this on my own as it is appears to be an issue on my end. Could I be receiving this error because of my Office/Windows/VBA version? If it helps I'm using Windows 7 x64 w/ office 2010. I'm tempted to try this with a fresh Windows install in a VM using multiple Office editions to test that theory but I feel like that might be time better spent actually learning VBA.

Comment: I've run through the new script you created with a fresh install of windows 7 using word 2013 and received error 91 on this line: Selection.TypeText "This is data"

Comment: When viewing the opened document I do see the line "This is data" has been writen to the first line but it is still giving me an error 91 on that line and will not continue the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
Este funciona correctamente (is OK)
</pre>


-------------------------
Option Explicit

Sub FirstPara()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strFolder As String, salFolder As String, docu As String, NombreCarpeta As String, strFile As String, wdDoc As Document
    Dim FirstPara As String
    Dim counter As Integer, a  As Integer, i  As Integer


    strFolder = GetFolder
    If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub

    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc*", vbNormal)
    i = 0
    a = 0
    Do While strFile <> ""
      i = i + 1
      strFile = Dir
    Loop
                   'MsgBox "value is " & i

    While a < i
        strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc*", vbNormal)
              docu = strFolder & "\" & strFile
        Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)

        With wdDoc
            FirstPara = .Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
            FirstPara = Left(FirstPara, Len(FirstPara) - 1)
            NewName = Replace(FirstPara, "\", "")
            NewName = Replace(NewName, "/", "")
            NewName = Replace(NewName, ":", "")
            NewName = Replace(NewName, """", "")
            NewName = Replace(NewName, vbCr, "")
            FirstPara = Replace(NewName, vbTab, "")
               'MsgBox "value is " & FirstPara
                NombreCarpeta = "\PROCESADOS"
                'Comprueba que la carpeta no existe para crearla.
                  If Dir(strFolder & NombreCarpeta, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir strFolder & NombreCarpeta
                  'MkDir se emplea para crear un directorio/carpeta.

            .SaveAs FileName:=strFolder & "\PROCESADOS\" & FirstPara & ".docx"
            .Close
             'Muevo el fichero a ORIGINALES.
                  NombreCarpeta = "\ORIGINALES"
                    'Comprueba que la carpeta no existe para crearla.
                  If Dir(strFolder & NombreCarpeta, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir strFolder & NombreCarpeta
                  'MkDir se emplea para crear un directorio/carpeta.

                FileCopy docu, strFolder & "\ORIGINALES\" & strFile
                Kill docu
          a = a + 1
        End With
        Set wdDoc = Nothing
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    GetFolder = ""
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
    If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function

-----------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub FirstPara()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strFolder As String, salFolder As String, docu As String, NombreCarpeta As String, strFile As String, wdDoc As Document
    Dim FirstPara As String
    Dim counter As Integer, a  As Integer, i  As Integer


    strFolder = GetFolder
    If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub

    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc*", vbNormal)
    i = 0
    a = 0
    Do While strFile <> ""
      i = i + 1
      strFile = Dir
    Loop
                   'MsgBox "value is " & i

    While a < i
        strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc*", vbNormal)
              docu = strFolder & "\" & strFile
        Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)

        With wdDoc
            FirstPara = .Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
            FirstPara = Left(FirstPara, Len(FirstPara) - 1)
            NewName = Replace(FirstPara, "\", "")
            NewName = Replace(NewName, "/", "")
            NewName = Replace(NewName, ":", "")
            NewName = Replace(NewName, """", "")
            NewName = Replace(NewName, vbCr, "")
            FirstPara = Replace(NewName, vbTab, "")
               'MsgBox "value is " & FirstPara
                NombreCarpeta = "\PROCESADOS"
                'Comprueba que la carpeta no existe para crearla.
                  If Dir(strFolder & NombreCarpeta, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir strFolder & NombreCarpeta
                  'MkDir se emplea para crear un directorio/carpeta.

            .SaveAs FileName:=strFolder & "\PROCESADOS\" & FirstPara & ".docx"
            .Close
             'Muevo el fichero a ORIGINALES.
                  NombreCarpeta = "\ORIGINALES"
                    'Comprueba que la carpeta no existe para crearla.
                  If Dir(strFolder & NombreCarpeta, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir strFolder & NombreCarpeta
                  'MkDir se emplea para crear un directorio/carpeta.

                FileCopy docu, strFolder & "\ORIGINALES\" & strFile
                Kill docu
          a = a + 1
        End With
        Set wdDoc = Nothing
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    GetFolder = ""
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
    If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```